# How do I hijack just one specific link within an LI and not ALL links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that in each `li`, it will have multiple `<a>` tags. The main one being the name of the item. When that one is clicked, I want a Dropdown event to happen. But on the items within the `<li>` I want those clicks to function normally.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="tree-item-name"><a href="#">Aunts &amp; Uncles</a>
    <span class = "bootstrap-styles">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="/family_trees/3"><img alt="Default" class="img-circle" height="48" src="/assets/default.jpg" width="48" /></a>
                <a href="/family_trees/3">Jackie Lynn</a> <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/family_trees/3" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </span>
 </li>
```

The JS looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('LI.tree-item-name').click(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            jQuery(this).find('UL').slideUp();
            jQuery(this).removeClass('opened');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('UL').slideDown();
            jQuery(this).addClass('opened');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

But right now, when you click on either the `img` tag or `Jackie Lynn`....neither work - because both are being hijacked by the JS.

How do I set this up so only `li.tree-item-name` is affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation and target only `li`s which has a `ul` inside it

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('LI.tree-item-name').has('ul').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
      $(this).find('UL').slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass('opened');
    } else {
      $(this).find('UL').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('opened');
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('LI.tree-item-name li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

```css
.tree-item-name ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tree-item-name">
    <a href="#">Aunts &amp; Uncles</a>
    <span class="bootstrap-styles">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/family_trees/3"><img alt="Default" class="img-circle" height="48" src="/assets/default.jpg" width="48" /></a>
          <a href="/family_trees/3">Jackie Lynn</a> <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/family_trees/3" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well answered, Arun. I was wondering exactly how to do that, and I chose a simpler solution. It is always a pleasure to see you working your jQuery-Fu. +1

Comment: Awesome...this is perfect. Just what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `a` tag (Aunts & Uncles) a class, and use that class as the jQuery click event trigger.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhp4q69L/)</kbd>

```
<li class="tree-item-name"><a class="rels" href="#">Aunts &amp; Uncles</a>
    <span class = "bootstrap-styles">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="/family_trees/3"><img alt="Default" class="img-circle" height="48" src="http://placekitten.com/g/48/48" width="48" /></a>
                <a href="/family_trees/3">Jackie Lynn</a> <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/family_trees/3" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </span>
</li>

jQuery('.rels').click(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('opened')) {
        jQuery(this).parent().find('UL').slideUp();
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().find('UL').slideDown();
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('opened');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are using (this) which takes care of the link you click on but then select the entire unordered list.
You need to put the url's on separate list item for it to work the way you have it.